# Deploy 2 sites from a single git repo

Tags: git, deployment, repository

I have 2 sites (staging and live). I want to have a central git repo where we push to and deploy both sites from.

I also need to capture changes that happen to the code on both the staging and live sites (plugin installation, themes, extensions, etc). I need ideas for the best structure please.

Obviously, our team will need to keep working copies of the central repo locally. Thanks!

Comment: Capistrano does this very well with [multistaging](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension); are you limited to using git commands only?

Comment: That looks awesome. Where does the repo reside though? Is it outside the working trees of live and staging? If so, how do we incorporate the changes that occur on the servers? Sorry, trying to get my head around this one!

Comment: Check out my answer for more details.

Comment: Regarding changes that are on the servers (but presumably not in development) - this is an extremely atypical setup.  Is there a reason you are allowing actual changes to be made to the server directly outside of file uploads?  If these are configuration files, there's no reason that development would need them, and if they are actual changes to code/assets, I would say that you have some wide-open security issues :)

Comment: I hear you Pinny, here's how it plays out: the install is Magento eCommerce community edition. The user/s need to install modules on the development site, test them and then push those to the live site instead of having to re-install those modules on the live/local sites again. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: In this case, the 'users' are actually co-developers working on the staging site (albeit with lesser permissions).  You can setup a tracking branch pointing to the deploy directory, and have Capistrano fetch/merge changes from the staging server repo before deploying, Then _after_ the deploy is complete, capistrano can reassign the tracking branch to the new directory/repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Capistrano with multistage deployments to handle what you want.  The repo being deployed can reside pretty much anywhere that is accessible for pulling by the app server environments.

For example, on a recent project we used a private GitHub repo as the deploying repository.  We set up SSH keys on the app server for authenticating with GitHub, and can deploy to either staging or production depending on the Capistrano command we issue from our local workstations.  Our local Capistrano instance will remotely (via SSH) tell the app server to checkout and fetch latest from the appropriate branch on Github to its own local repo, copy the latest code to a new directory, and then go through a checklist of tasks (config modifications, asset compilation, database migrations, etc).  Upon a successful deploy, Capistrano tells the server to switch over to the latest code.  Any hiccups, and it simply rolls back the deploy.

The command to deploy is as simple as: `cap deploy` or `cap production deploy`

You can read up more about it [here](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano), and about multistage setups [here](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension).

Answer (score 0):

What we use is two branches `master` and `production`. Usually development happens in `master` which is checked out on staging.

Once everything works fine we reset production to master and force push. Then we pull on live where `production` is checked out.
A script that does all this verifies that there are no unpushed changes on live before doing all that.

For hotfixes that need to be done in `production` we have a cherry-pick policy: changes that need to go to `master` need to be cherry-picked immediately.

Noteworthy is that we don't merge at all. We did but that didn't work out too god.